# How do I pull a random gif from tenor in discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm doing a discord bot using discord.py and one of the functions I want to add is on a command !gif it sends a random gif from tenor. Is it possible to do that? So basically what I need is an explanation as to how to fetch GIFs from tenor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to query Tenors random gif api:
https://tenor.com/gifapi/documentation#endpoints-random
This requires you to provide a search term and will return a randomised list of gif for that keyword.

You can then respond to the command with either a link to the gif or the gif itself as a file.

Comment: can u please give a code example for fetching the gif as a link?

Comment: nvm I alreaady figured it out. Thank you!